# Install Mac OS X SDK 10.5 on Snow Leopard

Tags: xcode, macos

Is there an easy way to install / download the Mac OS X 10.5 SDK on Snow Leopard?

I have Xcode 4.0 installed via the Mac App Store. I can also download it from the developer site if necessary but I don't know if it includes the 10.5 SDK.

**I need the 10.5 SDK for building Android.** It is a hard requirement stated in the docs. I tried symlinking to the 10.6 SDK but that didn't work.

(Perhaps it would be OK to get the SDK from an older Mac that is actually running 10.5 and has an older version of Xcode installed? Would that work?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 10.5 sdk is not available for XCode 4.0. You will need to keep XCode 3.2.6 if you need it.

Comment: Now that Xcode 4 is available I hope the Android build system gets updated.

Comment: 15 minutes of googling to find this answer. this is sad.

Answer (score 5):

There is a solution to install the Mac OS X SDK 10.5 on Snow Leopard shown here:

[How to add base SDK for 10.5 in xCode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5378518/how-to-add-base-sdk-for-10-5-in-xcode-4)

Basically, you can run the MacOSX10.5.pkg from an Xcode 3 installer and install the SDK into an Xcode 4 install.