# getting Mac OS X 10.5 sdk

Tags: android, osx-leopard

I'm trying to get android source code on Mac.

I've followed the guidelines on android webpage,

but when I try

```
    make -j4
```

it says MacOSX 10.5 SDK is not found at the directory.

I've done some search on it, but couldn't really find much info.

How could I install it at the specified directory?

Please help me out.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

So far it seems that the Android community hasn't updated the build process to work with any of the newer SDKs, so for now, you would need to get the 10.5 SDK by using an OS install disk (Snow Leopard or Leopard) and extracting the SDK from the Xcode installer that was included on the disk.  see here for more: [How to add base SDK for 10.5 in xCode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5378518/how-to-add-base-sdk-for-10-5-in-xcode-4)