# Has anyone succeeded in building the Android emulator with Lion?

Tags: android, android-source

I have a retina Macbook Pro running OSX 10.7, and I am trying to build Android from source.  However, I keep getting the error message "gcc is linked to llvm-gcc which will not create a useable emulator."

I tried downloading and using gcc, but got other errors.

Has anyone succeeded in building the Android emulator with OSX 10.7?

Comment: Should check with [android-building](http://groups.google.com/group/android-building) newsgroup over on google, that would be a better spot to ask around there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on OS X 10.6, but similarly I had troubles building ICS and older. The trick, it seems, is to grab the SDK for 10.6 (JB and up) or 10.5 (ICS and down).

Here's an answer that illustrates [how to get the 10.5 SDK on a 10.6 machine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6293605/154306).