# where do I go to download Mac OSX 10.5 SDK

Tags: macos, sdk

ALL,
Is there a link to download Mac OSX 10.5 SDK?
I have an original Snow Leopard disk with XCode 3.2.6. But when I checked it has 10.6 SDK not 10.5.

I need to link my program against 10.5 SDK.

Thank you.

Comment: Xcode 3.2.6 includes SDKs for 10.6 and 10.5.  It also optionally installs the 10.4u SDK.

Comment: @NedDeily, I looked at the original Snow Leopard CD in the Finder. Didn't see the file "*10.5*". Can you tell me where it is located? Thank you.

Comment: If you use the installer to install Xcode 3.2.6, it will install to `/Developer/SDKs`.  You can install 3.2.6 on 10.7 or 10.8 systems if you are careful about it; see for example http://catacombae.blogspot.com/2011/07/installing-xcode-326-in-mac-os-x-lion.html

Comment: @NedDeily, the problem is I have XCode 4.2 on my Snow Leopard, so all I need is SDK. I'm afraid that if I install XCode 3.2.6 my XCode 4.2 installation will go away.

Comment: During installation you can select a different directory to install 3.2.6 to.  Just make sure you deselect all subpackages except for `Essentials` as described in the blog entry.  You can also do a backup beforehand.  On my 10.8 system, I have Xcode 3.1.4, Xcode 3.2.6, Xcode 4.1, and Xcode 4.5.2 all installed.

Answer (score 1):

After registering with Apple as a developer, click on iOS as seen below. From there, click on "Download". Scroll through the versions until you find the one you would like, then click "Download" on the one you want!

As shown on [How to add base SDK for 10.5 in xCode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5378518/how-to-add-base-sdk-for-10-5-in-xcode-4), you have to open up the installer, extract your package, and then run the installer.  Once the package is installed, it should be compatible with later versions of xcode.

Comment: Can I get it for free somewhere? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken.  As long as you have a developer account(paid or unpaid), you should be able to access the tools you need. If you want to post to the app store however, you need a paid dev account.  Sorry about that!

Comment: Is 10.5 still available there?

Answer (score 1):

This site has multiple older Mac OS SDKs, including 10.5/Leopard (last accessed 2 Jan 2017):

[Releases * phracker/MacOSX-SDKs (on Github)](https://github.com/phracker/MacOSX-SDKs/releases)