# How to select XCode 3.2.6 with xcode-select?

Tags: xcode, osx-mavericks, xcodebuild

I have just upgraded my **Mac OS to 10.9.3** from a **Mac OS to 10.6.8**. I had a **XCode 3.2.6** installed. For new developments, I needed to install **XCode 4.5.2**.

In a maven build, I invoke xcodebuild to build some C++ projects. The problem is I need **xcodebuild 3.2.6** to build certain projects, and **xcodebuidl 4.5.2** for some new ones.

I need to be able to choose on-the-fly the xcodebuild version to launch a build on a project. I saw xcode-select could help me doing this, but I get stuck on the way to use **xcode-select** to choose **xcodebuild 3.2.6**.

Considerong my **XCode 4.5.2** is installed at **/Applications/Xcode.app**, using command

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

does the job, as

```
xcodebuild -version
```

outputs

```
Xcode 4.5.2
Build version 4G2008a
```

Considering my **XCode 3.2.6** is at **/Developer/Applications/Xcode.app**, my problem is, why does this command not work?

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app
```

It outputs

```
xcode-select: error: invalid developer directory '/Developer/Applications/Xcode.app'
```

The only workaround I could find is using the absolute path to use xcodebuild 3.2.6, but that's tricky:

```
/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild
```

Is there a clean way to select **xcodebuild 3.2.6** with xcode-select?

Comment: Does Mavericks support Xcode 3?

Comment: Not officially, you're right. I am able to build with XCode 3 though, using GUI or absolute path.

Comment: I expect, then, that it's `xcode-select` (which I *think* was only introduced in Xcode 4).  So for command line Xcode 3 builds you might have to manually construct paths to the compiler etc.  Why are you using Xcode 3/4 at all, however, and not Xcode 5 throughout?

Comment: I need building an InDesign plugin for a version that needs Mac OS 10.5 SDK support, what Xcode 3 is the only one to support. XCode 4 only supports 10.7+ SDK. I may use XCode 5 for later plugins...

Comment: Could you not take the Mac OS 10.5 SDK out of Xcode 3 and put it into the latest version of Xcode? That way you can just specify what SDK you are compiling against in the GUI or command line?

Comment: I've tried it, but it seems it is impossible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310368/install-mac-os-x-sdk-10-5-on-snow-leopard. Furthermore, I couldn't get it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like xcode-select has not been developed to be compatible with Xcode 3... I used absolute path instead, there seems to be no other way.

Answer (score 0):

You have to point path to `/Contents/Developer` folder in `Xcode.app` bundle.

Try this:

```
$ sudo xcode-select -switch /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Comment: I don't think I have to. I found several articles telling I could point to XCode.app or to XCode.app/Contents/Developer (and it works for XCode 4). Furthermore, there is no Contents/Developer folder in XCode 3

Answer (score -1):

Doesn't Xcode 3 install the Developer directory to /Developer on your Startup Disk?

Could you install Xcode 3 and then try:

```
$ sudo xcode-select -switch /Developer
```

Comment: xcode-select: error: invalid developer directory '/Developer'. I tried it in the past too, thinking the same as you. But it seems it does not work. Furthermore, each time I see a xcode-select documentation, XCode 3 is not mentionned.